# Webmin https Cookies

Tags: apache2, webmin

I have an issue that I need to enable https only cookies for the webmin site on one of my boxes. I do not see this setting in any of the config files under apache, webmin, or /var/www/html. Where do make this change?

Error:
Missing `secure` Cookie Attribute   Mitigation
Add NoteAdd Override Missing `httpOnly` Cookie Attribute

Comment: Where are you seeing this error?

Comment: In my greenbone security scanner.

Comment: The only way to change that is to alter how Webmin does cookies, if it's not an option in the Webmin panel, and it doesn't point its URLs to https://, then you need to ask Webmin to add that as a configurable option.  If it does point its URLs to HTTPS then it should be able to just do it.